# is there a way to make movement smoother in the Python Tk canvas?

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I am making a dot move around a screen, but it seems to pause(stop moving) for a bit when changing direction.

Is there a better way to make the movement smoother, or just stop the delay in changing directions?

Here is what i am using to move it:

```
def keypress(event):
    key = (event.keysym)

    if key == "w":
        canvas.move(player,0,-20)

    if key == "a":
        canvas.move(player,-20,0)

    if key == "s":
        canvas.move(player,0,20)

    if key == "d":
        canvas.move(player,20,0)

canvas.bind_all("<Key>", keypress)
```

Comment: Have you tried simply moving it in smaller increments? You're jumping 20 pixels every time you move.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Naming constants makes it easier to change them and experiment, especially when the same constant is used in multiple places in the code.  In the code below, you just need to change one copy of `20` to experiment, as Bryan suggested.

```
distance = 20
movements = {
    'w': (0, -distance),
    'a': (-distance, 0),
    's': (0, distance),
    'd': (distance, 0),
    }

def keypress(event):
    key = (event.keysym).lower()
    canvas.move(player, *movements[key])
```

While writing this, I took the opportunity to show how to use a dict to replace multiple conditionals by factoring out the common code from the changing code.  The * syntax in the move call separates the tuple into two arguments.